# Updated Xamarin Studio to version 6 is not supporting

Tags: xamarin-studio

I just recently update my Xamarin Studio on Mac to version 6. As I updated it and starts working on current project, It seems strange. Its showing red line below InitialiseComponent() of every class. Red line for every name of control which is declared in xaml file. Though it builds the app successfully. Lets say I declared Entry in xaml and named it as "username", in code behind I am not able to access any property of "username". 
Can somebody tell why this is happening with me.